# Bash script to run MySQL query

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm having issue connecting to MySQL and running a SQL query that is located in a directory.

This is what I have in the .sh file:

mysql -h hostname -P 3306 -u username -p password -A -e < /home/testing.sql

It returns an error "option '-e' requires an argument". The SQL file contains a simple create table statement in a schema I have access to.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just get rid of `-A -e `

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks for the tip, see comments below about the issue I'm running when removing -A and -e

Comment: Maybe you need to add something like `USE yourDatabaseName;` at the beginning of your script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there should be no space between -p and password. That resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The option `-e` expects a statement that shall be **e**xecuted, and you specified no such statement. To fix that, remove the `-e` option. The `-A` stands for disabling auto rehashing, but that option is on by default, so you can remove that as well. Your line should therefore look like this:

```
mysql -h hostname -P 3306 -u username -p password < /home/testing.sql
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it returns the same error as Luis Munoz's suggestion
Enter password:
after entering my MySQL db password, it says 
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'password'
It appears to be recognizing my password as the database name

Comment: This also has the strange effect of removing the contents of the .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
mysql -h hostname -P 3306 -u username -p password -A -e "$(cat /home/testing.sql)" your_database
```

Comment: I tried this and it returns 
Enter password:
after entering my MySQL db password, it says 
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'password'
It appears to be recognizing my password as the database name

Comment: Database name is missing at the end of the command in your question and in my answer :p. I edited mine, please fix yours.

Comment: Tried this with database name at the end and also with -D database name. Getting the same issue - thanks!